# AsyncTask, Android, and SQL

Tags: java, android

I originally posted this in stackoverflow.com but the question may be too broad.  I'm trying to figure out the best way to download and use an SQL database from my server.  I have included the code i whipped up but I'm not sure if it's a viable way to accomplish this so peer review would be extremely helpful :)

As it stands now, the database will be downloaded in a separate thread but when UI components are initialized they fail (obviously, as the database doesnt exist while its still being downloaded).

```
package com.sandbox.databaseone;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

public class DatabaseManager {

private SQLiteDatabase database;
private int currentVersion = 0;
private int nextVersion = 0;

private static String databasePath = "/data/data/com.sandbox.databaseone/databases/";
private static String databaseFile = "dbone.sqlite";

private static String databaseBaseURL = "http://www.redstalker.com/dbone/";
private static String databaseVersionURL = "version.txt";

public DatabaseManager()
{
    database = null;
}


public void initialize()
{
    DatabaseVersionCheck check = new DatabaseVersionCheck();

    String url = databaseBaseURL + databaseVersionURL;

    check.execute(url);
}

private void init_database(String path)
{
    database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    if(database != null)
    {
        currentVersion = nextVersion;
    }
    else
    {
        nextVersion = 0;
    }

}



private class DatabaseVersionCheck extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {


        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet get = new HttpGet(params[0]);

        try
        {
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);
            int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

            if(statusCode == 200)
            {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream in = entity.getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

                String line;

                while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    builder.append(line);
                }

                in.close();
                reader.close();
                entity.consumeContent();
            }

        } 

        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return builder.toString();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result)
    {
        if(result != null)
        {
            int version = Integer.parseInt(result);
            if(version > currentVersion)
            {
                nextVersion = version;

                DownloadDatabase d = new DownloadDatabase();
                d.execute();

            }
        }
    }
}

private class DownloadDatabase extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>
{

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {

        boolean result = false;
        String url = databaseBaseURL + databaseFile;
        String path = databasePath + databaseFile;

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url);

        try
        {
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);
            int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

            if(statusCode == 200)
            {
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(path);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream in = entity.getContent();

                byte [] buffer = new byte[1024];

                int count = 0;

                while((count = in.read(buffer)) != -1)
                {
                    fos.write(buffer, 0, count);
                }

                fos.close();
                in.close();
                entity.consumeContent();
                result = true;
            }

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result)
    {
        String path = databasePath + databaseFile;

        if(result)
        {
            init_database(path);
        }
    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some generic Java notes, since I'm not too familiar with Android.

1. `databasePath`, `databaseFile`, `databaseBaseURL`, `databaseVersionURL` should be constants (all uppercase with words separated by underscores):

   ```
   private static final String DATABASE_PATH = 
       "/data/data/com.sandbox.databaseone/databases/";
   private static final String DATABASE_FILE = "dbone.sqlite";
   private static final String DATABASE_BASE_URL = 
       "http://www.redstalker.com/dbone/";
   private static final String DATABASE_VERSION_URL =
       "version.txt";
   ```

   Reference: [Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language, 9 - Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367)
2. According to the previous Code Conventions, `init_database` should be `initDatabase`.
3. If `databaseBaseURL` and `databaseVersionURL` hadn't be constant I'd named them as `databaseBaseUrl` and `databaseBaseVersionUrl`. From *Effective Java, 2nd edition, Item 56: Adhere to generally accepted naming conventions*:

   > While uppercase may be more common, 
   >   a strong argument can made in favor of capitalizing only the first 
   >   letter: even if multiple acronyms occur back-to-back, you can still 
   >   tell where one word starts and the next word ends. 
   >   Which class name would you rather see, `HTTPURL` or `HttpUrl`?
4. ```
   public DatabaseManager()
   {
       database = null;
   }
   ```

   Initializing fields with `null` is unnecessary since `null` is the default value of references.
5. I'd call the `StringBuilder` in the `doInBackground` method as `result`.

   ```
   StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
   ```

   It would say what's the purpose of the object. For the same reason I'd rename the

   - `boolean result` to `boolean success`,
   - `in` to `responseStream`, and
   - `d` to `downloadDatabase`.
6. Close your streams in a `finally` block. In case of a previous errors they won't be closed.
7. The code does `databasePath + databaseFile` more than once. Create a method for that.
8. I don't know if it is applicable to Android or not, but in Java it's a good practice to pass the character set to the constructor of `InputStreamReader`. Without this `InputStreamReader` uses the default charset which could vary from system to system.

   ```
   BufferedReader reader = 
       new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8"));
   ```
9. I'd use [Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/)'s [IOUtils](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html) for the copying. It has a `copy(InputStream input, OutputStream output)` which you could use in the `DownloadDatabase` task and you could use `copy(InputStream input, Writer output)` in the `DatabaseVersionCheck` task if you replace the `StringBuilder` to a `StringWriter`.
10. In the `DatabaseVersionCheck.onPostExecute` I'd use guard clauses:

    ```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if(result == null) {
            return;
        }

        int version = Integer.parseInt(result);
        if(version <= currentVersion) {
            return;
        }

        nextVersion = version;

        DownloadDatabase d = new DownloadDatabase();
        d.execute();
    }
    ```

    It makes the code flatten and more readable. References: *Replace Nested Conditional with Guard Clauses* in *Refactoring: Improving the Design of Existing Code*; [Flattening Arrow Code](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/01/flattening-arrow-code.html)
11. `e.printStackTrace()` is not the best practice. Maybe you should inform the user about the error and/or log it.

    - [Why is exception.printStackTrace() considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7469316/why-is-exception-printstacktrace-considered-bad-practice)
    - [Is it a bad idea to use printStackTrace() in Android Exceptions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3855187/is-it-a-bad-idea-to-use-printstacktrace-in-android-exceptions)
12. `Integer.parseInt` could throw `NumberFormatException`. Maybe the code should handle it.

Comment: Wow... you really just schooled me in Java.  I will definitely take this to heart and study up to improve, I appreciate it.  Hopefully my next version will be cleaner.